# FortiGate HA (A/A) Cluster: How can I manage the slave unit from the web GUI?

Tags: router, ipv4, firewall, ip, fortigate

I am confused to what happened to the slave's IP address. Before I set both my units to Active/Active cluster, I could reach each of them with their own IP. Now, I can still reach the master unit with the same IP. However: I can no longer reach my slave unit on the IP I used to reach it on prior to setting up the Cluster. What happened to it?

Do they share the same IP now that they are in a cluster? If so: How can I manage each of them from the web interface?

If not: Is there any way I can find the other unit without scanning my entire network manually?

The specific units I'm operating are `FortiGate 60D`

**EDIT:**
From what I can tell: They do share the same IP. A lot of my results on Google comes up with the CLI command: `exec ha manage 1`. I appear to be in the slave unit when I run that command. So now when I try to retrieve the IP address using this command: `get system interface`: It gives me the same IP address as my master unit have on the internal interface.

Is there any way I can manage the slave interface from the HTML GUI?

*I've been "Googling" around for the last 5 hours with no progress.*

Comment: Typically, you manage the cluster. What you do on the master is synchronized to the slave, and you don't manage the slave separately since it needs to mirror the master.

Comment: @RonMaupin Oh. It all makes sense now. Totally new to this clustering concept :) Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clustered Fortigate units become ONE unit in terms of L3 IP addresses, L2 MAC addresses, policies, objects etc. Only a few HA parameters along with the hostname are not mirrored from master to slave(s). The primary's IP addresses are used for the cluster; all slave addresses are overwritten. The real MAC addresses are hidden as well.

Active management of a slave unit is so uncommon that it's restricted to the CLI. Rebooting, shutting down, separating from the cluster come to my mind. To monitor CPU, memory and throughput you have GUI controls in System > Config > HA > HA statistics.

There's an exception to every rule. On Fortigate models starting in midrange (100D and up) you often find 'management ports'. These are physical ports which you can dedicate to management only - they will not route. They are the only ports that can be in the same subnet as other ports on the Fortigate. You can connect to each cluster unit then via GUI.
The Fortigate 60D does not have these special kind of ports.

Answer (score 0):

> execute ha manage ?

You need to run this from the CLI. Once the primary is active, the slave is inaccessible via the IP.

> execute ha manage ?

This command, including the (space) "?" gives the results of a number ie: 0 or 1
0 is generally the primary, whereas 1 is generally the secondary.

If in the primary:

> execute ha manage 1

This will take you to the secondary

> execute ha manage 0

This will take you from the secondary to the primary

Comment: "Typically, you manage the cluster. What you do on the master is synchronized to the slave, and you don't manage the slave separately since it needs to mirror the master. – Ron Maupin"-
-
-

The HA partnership may be providing not only redundancy or load balancing, but even multiple ISPs and failover internet access or more; accessing the slave becomes imperative for testing.

Answer (score 0):

With the 6000 chassis models, you can use https://IP:44320 To access the slave cluster members GUI. The last digit 0 is for the MDB master board (2220 for SSH, 2230 telnet, 16120 SNMP).
You can access the FPC's (1-6 last digit on the 6k models)

You could try https://IP:44320   (44330, 44340, etc, if you have more cluster members. The cluster member is the 4th Digit and the 5 is the MDS/FPC if relevant)